# Grails resource plugin reload failed

Tags: file, grails, resources

am using grails 2.3. I saved image using

```
    def path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") 
    def imgpath = path +"heatmap\\" + date.getTime().toString()+".png"        
    def image = new File(imgpath)
    image.setBytes(bytes)
```

Image created but getting error why??:

```
Resource reload failed!:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'grailsResourceProcessor' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure20.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:204)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure20.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1283)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:191)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1283)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.call(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.call(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.run(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I filled a bug in the resources plugin some time ago: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-228

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug and it has been fixed. A fix is available on following location.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/76cd2fce8783fa6c5cdc0f71d890c90c32146476/ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy

Just download this file and replace your ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy content with this.

All the best.